# How to get window principle id of client machine (asp.net)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, active-directory, httpwebrequest

I want to get the client window username with which the user is logged in on their  machine,

I have tried these:

```
Request.servervariable["LOGON_USER"],
Request.servervariable["AUTH_USER"],
Request.servervariable["REMOTE_USER"]
```

but when I deploy my application on IIS the values of all these are blank,
some constraints are applied for my app senario: I am using the authentication mode ="form"
because I am passing the Windows account username to db, then I'm authenticating if this Windows user id is present in db.

Similarly I want anonymous access in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've enabled windows authentication, Page.User.Identity.Name should give you that!

Comment: i said before window authetication is not required i want to do this in form authentication i only want username and pass it to db to verfiy if not, i want to login user with custom credential.